# Автономные карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, я могу добавить Яндекс карты в десктопный проект на QT, чтобы карты отображались даже без подключения к интернету? Если да, то как?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Для использования API Яндекс.Карт в закрытых проектах, коим несомненно является ваш проект в любом случае требуется приобретение [коммерческой лицензии](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/commercial/doc/concepts/jsapi-geocoder.html#jsapi-geocoder__standart) сервиса. А с необходимостью сохранять данные ещё и [расширенной](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/commercial/doc/concepts/jsapi-geocoder.html#jsapi-geocoder__tariff-plus).

Однако [JS API](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/quick-start/index-docpage/) не предоставляет методов кэширования или загрузки самих карт. Более того сам API подключается именно онлайн, хотя и кэшируется браузером для ускорения последующих загрузок. Поэтому доступ в сеть в любом случае обязателен.

Единственная возможность работы с загруженными картами - [коммерческий MapKit](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/commercial/doc/concepts/mapkit.html#mapkit__about-tariffs).